# Cut out a smaller array shape from a bigger array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have two sets of data in x and y arrays, one is from a theoretical calculation so it is far larger.

```
x1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] y1 = [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]
```

the other is experimental so it has the same values of x (but with a smaller data set, different start and different intervals) with slightly different y values

```
x2 = [3,5,7,9]              y2 = [10,23,46,82]
```

How can I make the 1st theoretical arrays or data have the same shapes. I want to effectively cut out 3rd/5th/7th values of the 1st arrays, making the arrays have the same shapes.

ie

```
x1_new = [3,5,7,9]  y1_new = [9,25,49,81]
```

Comment: try this `x1_new  = x1[2::2]` and `y1_new  = y1[2::2]`

Comment: You should use `numpy`. `import numpy as np; y1_new = np.array(y1)[np.array(x2)-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python way:

```
y1_new = [y1[x-1] for x in x2]
```

Or learn numpy:

```
import numpy as np
y1_new = np.array(y1)[np.array(x2)-1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using numpy,  however my arrays are floats, and I don't want to convert them to integers

Comment: You need to have integers for indexing

Comment: so there is no possible way to do this with floats? if so, thanks a lot anyway. I can probably see if I can just make another theoretical array with the same dimensions as the experimental.